# How to check XML nodes contained in different XML files for equality?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have two XML files (file A and file B where file A is a subset of file B) which I read using the `System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(fileName)` method.

I am then selecting nodes within these files using the `System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes(nodeName)` I need to compare that each selected xml node in file A is either equal or a subset of that same node in file B. Need to also check that the order of the subnodes contained within any node in file A is the same of the order of those same subnodes contained within that node in fileB.

For example,

**fileA**

```
<rootNodeA>
 <elementA>
  <subelementA>content</subElementA>
  <subelementB>content</subElementB>
  <subelementB>content</subElementC>
  <subelementB>content</subElementD>
 </elementA>
 <elementB>
  <subelementA>content</subElementA>
  <subelementB>content</subElementB>
 </elementB>
</rootNodeA>
```

**fileB**

```
<rootNodeB>
 <elementA>
  <subelementB>content</subElementB>
  <subelementD>content</subElementD>
 </elementA>
 <elementB>
  <subelementA>content</subElementA>
 </elementB>
</rootNodeB>
```

As you see, fileB is a subset of fileA. I need to check that `elementA` node of file B is equal or a subset of that same `elementA` node in file A. This should be true for the subnodes (`subElementA`, etc.) as well and the content of the nodes/subnodes.

Also, if you see `elementA` in fileA, there are 4 *subelements* in the order A,B,C,D. For that same `elementA` in fileB, there are 2 *subelements* in the order A,D. This order i.e A comes before D is same as the order in file A, need to check this as well.

My idea is to compute Hashes of the nodes and then compare them but unsure of how or if this would satisfy the purpose.

**EDIT:** Code I have so far,

```
    HashSet<XmlElement> hashA = new HashSet<XmlElement>();
    HashSet<XmlElement> hashB = new HashSet<XmlElement>();

                foreach (XmlElement node in nodeList)
                {
                    hashA.Add(node);
                }
                foreach(XmlElement node in masterNodeList)
                {
                    hashB.Add(node);
                }
                isSubset = new HashSet<XmlElement>(hashA).IsSubsetOf(hashB);
            return isSubset;
```

Comment: You have a clear goal, but have you tried anything yet? If so, could you edit the relevant code into your question?

Comment: How fast it should be? Do you care about it (for small files like 1MB or less you don't have to make any long-code (-> meaning fast and more complicated) solution). Also - do you care about content - should the content be the same or only subelements?

Comment: You cannot test for equality with hashes, only inequality. If you want to test if B is a subset of A; loop through every element of B and test whether A contains that element.

Comment: I added the code I have so far @BrootsWaymb

Comment: @kademat I don't care about speed, I do care that the content is equal as well.

Comment: `XmlElement` instances are not comparable. Two elements with identical markup will still not be the same *object*, especially not when they belong to different documents. To make things worse, XML allows different but equivalent ways of writing the same element, so typically you want some form of XML canonicalization applied before you start comparing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like a simple recursive function.

didn't check if it actually work, but that should do it:

```
public static bool isSubset(XmlElement source, XmlElement target)
    {
        if (!target.HasChildNodes)
        {
            if (source.HasChildNodes) // surly not same.
                return false;
            return string.Equals(source.Value, target.Value); // equalize values.
        }

        var sourceChildren = source.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToArray(); // list all child tags in source (by order)
        var currentSearchIndex = 0; // where are we searching from (where have we found our match)

        foreach (var targetChild in target.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>())
        {
            var findIndex = Array.FindIndex(sourceChildren, currentSearchIndex, el => el.Name == targetChild.Name);
            if (findIndex == -1)
                return false; // not found in source, therefore not a subset.

            if (!isSubset(sourceChildren[findIndex], targetChild))
                return false; // if the child is not a subset, then parent isn't too.

            currentSearchIndex = findIndex; // increment our search index so we won't match nodes that already passed.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would not check if the content of the source and target is also equal

Comment: just add a condition if Children.count == 0... check content

Comment: It returns as false for two elements which are exactly the same, not sure how to debug your solution.

Comment: use visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for your tip @Tomer W, issue was it was capturing the whitespace as well, loading the files initially with `XMLDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false` solved that issue.

Comment: Good job. also, you can use `string.Equals(source.Value.Trim(), target.Value.Trim());` to ignore whitespace from matching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180068/discussion-between-vdrog-and-tomer-w).